# Parsing problem

Tags: rooting

I have been trying to root my Le Pan II android tablet with Kingo root app, and when I try to install I keep get error parsing problem. What would be the easiest way to root my tablet?

Comment: For the starter, quote the correct error message. Provide the screenshot to make it clear. Or else, try [this method from Android Forums](http://androidforums.com/threads/root.504542/)

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution. First go to your application list in your settings and navigate to "all "section. See and check that an system application called mtk logger is present there or not. If it is present, i can definitely help you. If it is there then download an application "framaroot" 1.9.5 and install it. Open it and select any option present below. Then wait the process to be finished. Then reboot your phone. Your phone is now rooted.